# rails 4 form with multiple models not showing nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

User model - built with devise.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
// some stuff 
has_one :expert
accepts_nested_attributes_for :expert, :update_only => true
// more stuff
```

Expert model - built withOUT devise.

```
class Expert < ActiveRecord::Base  
belongs_to :user
```

User controller:

```
def edit
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Edit Profile"
end
```

Expert controller:

```
def edit
  @expert = Expert.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Edit Expert Profile"
end
```

Edit user view form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Password %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :password, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <% f.fields_for :expert do |e| %>
      <%= e.label :Location %><br />
      <%= e.text_field :Location %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The part of the form which is supposed to display the :Location field for the expert model does not display on the view.. screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/JifVuv7.png

Can't figure out why this is happening, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per ERB syntax, you need to use:

`<%= %>` to execute the enclosed ruby code  + render results 
 `<% %>` to execute the enclosed ruby code

You used `<% %>` for `f.fields_for` which is why the nested fields were not rendered.

Change the code as below:

```
<%= f.fields_for :expert do |e| %>
  <%= e.label :Location %><br />
  <%= e.text_field :Location %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Now the fields display but I have a new problem. When I modify any of the expert model fields and submit the form it gives me the error: You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. I have this in the User controller: before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show, :edit]. I've  created a new question for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013331/rails-4-nested-form-with-devise-logs-me-out-on-update